# Reducing an axis with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have an `NxMx3` numpy array with `dtype=object`.  I also have a function `f(a,b,c)` which takes the three elements in the last axis of this array and returns a `np.int32`.  My question is how do I apply `f` to my `NxMx3` array to yield an `NxM` array with `dtype=np.int32`?

My current solution is to use

```
newarr = np.fromfunction(lambda i,j: f(arr[i,j,0], arr[i,j,1], arr[i,j,2]),
                          arr.shape[:2], dtype=np.int)
```

although this is a little more verbose than I had hoped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

```
np.vectorize(f, otypes=[np.int32])(arr[:, :, 0], arr[:, :, 1], arr[:, :, 2])
```

This can be simplified by axis rolling and iteration:

```
np.vectorize(f, otypes=[np.int32])(*np.rollaxis(arr, 2, 0))
```

Alternatively you can split the array explicitly with `dsplit`:

```
np.vectorize(f, otypes=[np.int32])(*np.dsplit(arr, 3))[..., 0]
```

or

```
np.vectorize(f, otypes=[np.int32])(*np.dsplit(arr, 3)).reshape(arr.shape[:-1])
```

or

```
np.vectorize(f, otypes=[np.int32])(*np.dsplit(arr, 3)).squeeze()
```

However, `apply_along_axis` is probably simpler:

```
np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: f(*x), 2, arr)
```

Comment: Angry +1 -- I thought I was going to beat you to `apply_along_axis`. :^)